# How does timer interrupts work on TI AM64x

Tags: c++, timer

I never used timers for embedded micro controller programming, so there are several things I would like to learn about. I am using the TI AM64x chip and try to understand the example in the [AM64x Timer SDK Guide](https://software-dl.ti.com/mcu-plus-sdk/esd/AM64X/latest/exports/docs/api_guide_am64x/KERNEL_DPL_TIMER_PAGE.html):

```
TimerP_Params timerParams;
/* setup timer but dont start it */
TimerP_Params_init(&timerParams);
timerParams.inputPreScaler    = 1u;
timerParams.inputClkHz        = 250u*1000u*1000u;
timerParams.periodInUsec      = 10u*1000u;
timerParams.oneshotMode       = 0;
timerParams.enableOverflowInt = 1;
TimerP_setup(timerBaseAddr, &timerParams);
```

To my understanding the timer can trigger 3 different interrupts (overflow, match, compare). But exactly when and how are these interrupts triggered?

**Overflow**

1. Is this triggered after `periodInUsec` or once the 32bit counter is overflown? I need to trigger an interrupt after a certain time.
2. If `enableOverflowInt` is enabled, is the interrupt automatically triggered? How do I capture the interrupt in my code? Or do I need to deal with it manually, like this:

```
while(true) {
  if(TimerP_isOverflowed(timerBaseAddr)) {
    // do stuff...
  }
  TimerP_clearOverflowInt(timerBaseAddr)
}
```

**Match, Compare**

How do I "activate" these interrupts? The timer parameters seem to have no settings for these triggers (like `enableOverflowInt`). However there is this function `TimerP_getCount(timerBaseAddr)`, but it will return the 32bit counter value. So I need to convert the time value and compare it to the counter value? And I have to do it manually again?

Further information: [AM64x User Guide](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruim2f/spruim2f.pdf?ts=1689194708991&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FAM2431) (Chapter 12.5.3 Timers; page 8061).
Thanks a lot for your help!